# jQuery multiple function for checkbox

Tags: jquery

this is what i use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $("#companyname");
  var b = $(".companyname");
  b.hide();
  a.change(function() {
    if (a.is(':checked')) {
      b.show();
    } else {
      b.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

PHP

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
  // output data of each row 
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<div class='hide'><h4 class='period'>". $row["PeriodFrom"]." to ".$row["PeriodTo"]."</h4><h4 class='companyname'>". $row["CompanyName"]. "</h4><h4 class='city'>".$row["City"].", " .$row["Country"]."<h4 class'jobt'>" . $row["JobTitle"] . "<p class='info'>".$row["Responsibilities"]."</p>" . "</div>"; } 
} else {
     echo "0 results"; 
}
```

But I was wondering if there is an option to make a multiple function? Instead of writing the same code for each checkbox.

```html
<form>
  <h1>Filter</h1> 
  <input id="checkperiod" type="checkbox" name="period"> Period 
  <input id="companyname" type="checkbox" name="companyname">Company Name 
  <input id="city" type="checkbox" name="city"> City and Country
  <input id="jobt" type="checkbox" name="jobtitle">Job
  Title 
  <input if="info" type="checkbox" name="info"> Info and Responsibilities 
</form>
```

Comment: <form>
            <h1>Filter</h1>
            <input id="checkperiod" type="checkbox" name="period"> Period
            <input id="companyname" type="checkbox" name="companyname">Company Name
            <input id="city" type="checkbox" name="city"> City and Country
            <input id ="jobt" type="checkbox" name="jobtitle">Job Title
            <input if="info" type="checkbox" name="info"> Info and Responsibilities
        </form>

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='hide'><h4 class='period'>". $row["PeriodFrom"]." to ".$row["PeriodTo"]."</h4><h4 class='companyname'>". $row["CompanyName"]. "</h4><h4 class='city'>".$row["City"].", " .$row["Country"]."<h4 class'jobt'>" . $row["JobTitle"] . "<p class='info'>".$row["Responsibilities"]."</p>" . "</div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

Comment: I have added an example in my answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give all the checkboxes a specific class and use a selector to bind event to all checkboxes. From what I understand from your code, the related element to show/hide has class name same as the related checkbox. Also since it is just a simple show/hide case, you can use [**`toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

**Edit**: What `$('.' + this.name)` does is that we are creating a class selector like you did in `var b = $(".companyname");`. Since the element needs to be hidden is the one with class name same as the checkbox name we concatenate the `.` with `this.name` (`this.name` will get the name of the checkbox).

I am adding an example below. I made some tweeks in the HTML.

```js
$('#filterForm input:checkbox').change(function() {
  if($('#filterForm input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){
    $('#filterDiv').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#filterDiv').addClass('hide');
  }
  if(this.checked){
    $('.' + this.name).removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.' + this.name).addClass('hide');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.hide{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="filterForm">
  <h1>Filter</h1> 
  <input id="checkperiod" type="checkbox" name="period"> Period 
  <input id="companyname" type="checkbox" name="companyname">Company Name 
  <input id="city" type="checkbox" name="city"> City and Country
  <input id="jobt" type="checkbox" name="jobtitle">Job
  Title 
  <input if="info" type="checkbox" name="info"> Info and Responsibilities 
</form>

<div id="filterDiv" class="hide">
  <h4 class='period hide'>PeriodFrom to PeriodTo</h4>
  <h4 class='companyname hide'>CompanyName</h4>
  <h4 class='city hide'>
    City, Country.
  </h4>
  <h4 class='jobtitle hide'>JobTitle</h4>
  <p class='info hide'>Responsibilities</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you meant  $('#' + this.id).toggle(this.checked); 
and actually why do not try also  $(this.).toggle(this.checked); ?

Comment: @MicheleDibenedetto Of course not. From the OP we can deduct that the element he wants to toggle is an element with classname same as the ID of the checkbox. Also `$(this.).toggle(this.checked)` on the checkbox will hide itself, so how can that be useful?

Answer (score -1):

this should answer your question, but now my question is, 
how do you think to show back your checkbox if when you it is unchecked it is hidden then not clickable to be shown again?

```js
$('.options').change(function() { 
  $(this).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<form> <h1>Filter</h1> 
<input id="checkperiod" class="options" type="checkbox" name="period"> Period
<input id="companyname"class="options"  type="checkbox" name="companyname">Company Name 
<input id="city" class="options"  type="checkbox" name="city"> City and Country 
<input id ="jobt"class="options"  type="checkbox" name="jobtitle">Job Title 
<input id="info" class="options"  type="checkbox" name="info"> Info and Responsibilities 
</form>
```